# Tagging / generating a method link in typedoc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, typedoc

What markup should we use to tag that something is a method in typedoc.  For example I have the following comment:

```
  /**
   * The index for all of the ValidationContext instances.
   * Not meant to be accessed directly.  Only decorators should
   * be modifying the state of the cache by using the addValidationContext() method.
   */
```

How do I tell typedoc that `addValidationContext` is a method on the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeDoc has two methods for setting links. For methods and properties, you should be able to write `[[ClassName.methodName]]` or `{@link ClassName.methodName}` and have that converted to a link.

If you look at the [doc comment](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/blob/3581d04f8d62d76897fb3f9732bdf6cbfc33c731/src/lib/output/renderer.ts#L40) for the Renderer class you can see an example which is rendered in the [api documentation site](http://typedoc.org/api/classes/renderer.html).

Comment: **Our Intellij 2019 based IDEs did not suppurt `[[namesapce]]` syntax**, but `{@link namespace}` syntax did work.

Answer (score 2):

You may use JSDoc [{@link}](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-inline-link.html) or [@see](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-see.html) instructions.